# Mockito - Test if a method of a class is called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new to writing tests in java, and seem to be unable to test if a method of a class is called.

I am sending metrics to datadog, and want to test in the code if a function of another class was called.

It says I need to mock first, but I couldn't get it to work.

MetricRecorder.java

```
import com.timgroup.statsd.StatsDClient;
import com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClient;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;

public class MetricRecorder {
    private final String namespace;
    private final static StatsDClient metrics = new NonBlockingStatsDClient(
      "my.prefix",                          
      "localhost",                          
      8125,                                 
      new String[] {"tag:value"} 
    );

    public MetricRecorder(String namespace) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(namespace);
        this.namespace = namespace;
    }

    public void inc(String metricName) {
        this.inc(metricName, 1);
    }

    public void inc(final String metricName, final long value) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(metricName);
        try {
            metrics.recordHistogramValue(MetricRecorder.name(namespace, metricName), value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to record metric {} due to :", metricName, e);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

MetricRecorderTest.java

```
public class MetricsRecorderTest {

    @Test
    public void metricsRecorderTest() {
        MetricRecorder recorder = new MetricRecorder("dev");
        recorder.inc("foo", 1);
        verify(recorder.metrics, times(1)).recordHistogramValue(eq("dev.foo"), 1);
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get this => org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type NonBlockingStatsDClient and is not a mock!

Any idea of how I should be testing if recordHistogramValue was called, and if so with what arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like `StatsDClient` is an interface of some kind, it would make your testing effort easier to simply inject this dependency into your object.  Even if you're not using an IoC container like Spring or Guice, you can still somewhat control this simply by passing an instance of it in through the constructor.

```
public MetricRecorder(String namespace, StatsDClient client) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(namespace);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(client);
    this.namespace = namespace;
    this.client = client;
}
```

This will make your testing simpler since all you realistically need to do is mock the object passed in during test.

Right now, the reason it's failing is because you're `new`ing up the instance, and Mockito (in this current configuration) isn't equipped to mock the newed instance.  In all honesty, this set up will make testing simpler to conduct, and you should only need your client configured in one area.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MetricsRecorderTest {

    @Test
    public void metricsRecorderTest() {
        StatsDClient dClientMock = Mockito.mock(StatsDClient.class);
        MetricRecorder recorder = new MetricRecorder("dev", dClientMock);
        recorder.inc("foo", 1);
        verify(recorder.metrics).recordHistogramValue(eq("dev.foo"), 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I use this constructor pattern in addition to the constructor that I already have? I think this would work technically....Only other change I would have to make is public final static StatsDClient metrics to private static StatsDClient metrics...It has to be public to test recorder.metrics, and it can't be final either.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting things wrong here. You don't use a **mocking** framework to test your "class under test".

You use the mocking framework to create **mocked** objects; which you then pass to your "class under test" within a test case. Then your "code under test" calls methods on the mocked object; and by controlling returned values (or by verifying what happens to your mock); that is how you write your testcases.

So, your testcase for a MetricRecorder doesn't mock a MetricRecorder; it should mock the StatsDClient class; and as Makoto suggests; use **dependency** injection to put an object of that class into MetricRecorder.

Besides: basically writing "test-able" code is something that needs to be practiced. I wholeheartedly recommend you to watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) if you are serious about getting in this business. All of them; really (worth each second!).